# ajax issues in updating view count

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have a simple table with a few columns.  I am updating a view count in the database, but the problem is that I am making some ajax calls every 20 seconds.  I just want to count the page views, but the AJAX calls are also also being counted as views.

My code is very simple.

```
$res = sql_query("select * from tableA where user='XYZ'");
sql_query("update tableA set views=views+1  ");
```

This does the job, but due to AJAX it keeps on increasing the views count in the database.  Can anyone help me so that I can count only actual views, not the AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<body onload="your function goes here">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a change to the logic that updates the page hits.  Check for the AJAX HTTP header (see here: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax), and only update the table accordingly.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    sql_query("update tableA set views=views+1  ");
}
```